# Tab key doesn't work for Rmarkdown files in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

This issue has bothered me for a while. The tab key does not produce anything when typing in the content part of any Rmarkdown file BUT works pretty well in the code chunks. Is it a bug or I need to setup something ahead? It's very annoying to often type spaces in the yaml and when creating the bullet points.

I'm using Rstudio Version 1.3.314 and updated `Rmarkdown` package directly from the github repo on a Win10 PC.